# Bandwidth option in kovri

Tags: kovri, i2p, bandwidth

From kovri command line help, bandwith default parameter is the character "L"

> -b [ --bandwidth ] arg (=L)

What does it represent and what are the possible values ?

Answer (score 3):

This setting is adopted from the original i2pd and the [documentation](https://i2pd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/) tells:

> Bandwidth limit: integer in KBps or letters: L (32), O (256), P (2048), X (>9000)